# Nextcloud LDAP groups empty

Tags: active-directory, ldap, nextcloud

I have Nextcloud 18.0.3 on docker.
Nextcloud is connected to an Active Directory instance.

Login via AD/LDAP works fine.

**LDAP config app:**

**Users Tab:**

Verify and count users: >1000
Only from these groups: displays all my AD groups

**Groups Tab**

Verify settings and count groups: 391

Group-Member Association: member(AD), each AD group has one member attribute per member.

So my AD settings seem to be pretty valid.

Alas, I do not see my AD/LDAP groups anywhere.
- not when trying to share a folder to a group
- not when assigning a group to a user

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, seems to be a known bug in 18.0.[23]. More info: https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/19970

**tl;dr;**

Download patch from https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/19970#issuecomment-603724938, install patch and enjoy